# Scheduled tasks not working when run on remote instance

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-ec2, ansible, scheduled-tasks

I have a `AWS ec2` windows server running. I have a `powershell script` running to schedule a task to hourly run a program that generates a report, and collect it in a folder. When this task is manually run by clicking through the scheduler, the output comes out fine. But, when I run my script to run it, everything seems to be working fine, but the reports are not collected in the folder. I've tried several variations of the schedulers options, but the fact that it works with a manual run makes me think that is not the issue. I'm also running the powerhsell script from an `ansible` script.

**scheduletask.ps1:**

```
`$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
schtasks /query /tn "RunNetSparker"""
if ($?)
{
SCHTASKS /DELETE /TN "RunNetSparker" /F
}
schtasks /create /RU Administrator /RP "{{ win_initial_password }}" /tn RunNetSparker /xml "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Netsparker_Files\scheduleschema.xml" /f`
```

**This is the configuration xml:**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2018-05-04T13:51:42</Date>
    <Author>Administrator</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <TimeTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT10M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2018-05-04T15:30:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </TimeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-18</UserId>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>Parallel</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>false</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Netsparker_Files\NetScanConfig.bat</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>`
```

Comment: Does the user that runs the task has the propper permissions to run it?

Comment: Also, does the user that it runs as have access to the folder where it's supposed to be putting it?

Comment: It is being run as administrator, so yes, permissions shouldn't be the issue